# OAuth redirect flow server to server token generation for client

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, jwt, authorization

I have a rest API service that enables API calls for some resources.
The API calls can be done from an API server using a secret, or from a web client using a bearer token.
In order to get to the web client flow, a URL must be generated by the API server call:

`https://www.someapi.com/somelink`

The response will be a link with a token I call "action token". This token is passed with the link, for example:

`https://www.somepage.com/?action_token=somejwttoken`

By entering the link, the action token will be exchanged with an access token, that enables a client to access some pre-defined resources.

I wonder if there is a best practice for such flow.

Answer (score 0):

**ONE TIME TOKENS**

If using tokens in URLs you should also ensure that:

- The token has a one time use
- The token is short lived
- The token is not guessable - eg make it a UUID
- The final access token returned has limited privileges and also a short lifetime

The one time `action token` may then be available in the browser history or server logs, so be aware of that. Make the actual swap for the proper token a JSON to JSON POST operation, after the page has loaded.

Typically each action token issued would also be stored by the API in a database along with its expiry time, then used to verify links later.

This type of URL solution is sometimes used in operations such as `verify email` or to enable `magic links`, where users can quickly access limited data.

**OAUTH FLOWS**

One time tokens should not be overused and they are of course no substitute for signing the user in properly via [OpenID Connect standards](https://curity.io/resources/learn/openid-connect-standards/), then running an authenticated user session.

**SCOPES AND API TO API FLOWS**

A more secure option may be to forward JWTs from the original client to downstream APIs, as described in [Scopes Best Practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/scope-best-practices/). This enables user context to flow securely and also simplifies code. This may eliminate or reduce the need for any `token exchange` operations.